# passing data into function in jquery.on()

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery code:

```
$(document).delegate('.draggable','mousedown', function() {
...
var connected_nodes = $(".linked-to" + node_num);   //all the nodes connected to the selected node
    var lines = $("div[id*='"+node_num+"']");   //all the lines which are connected to selected node
...
$(this).on('mousemove.link', dragNodes);

    function dragNodes(connected_nodes, lines)
    {
...
```

I am trying to pass connected_nodes and lines into the function. I tried doing

```
$(this).on('mousemove.link', dragNodes(connected_nodes, lines));
```

and then everything stopped working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the context where both `connected_nodes` and `.on()` are actually being used

Comment: Yea.. please show the full context... this looks very very wrong...

Comment: @user1015214, that is not even close. At this point, you should better explain what you are trying to achieve since it seems you are reluctant to show more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Since it doesn't look like you want to expand the question. I shall try answering with what is available.)*

Try:

```
$(this).on('mousemove.link', function(){
  dragNodes(connected_nodes, lines);
});
```

Comment: Sorry that I didn't elaborate the question, I had to rush away.

Comment: But thanks, that works. Can you explain to me the difference between your code and mine and why yours is the correct way to call a function with parameters?